# Cordova save image path of a rotated image

Tags: android, image, cordova, orientation

How can I store the path of a picture taken from camera photolibrary into my database?
There's no problem with `horizontal pictures` because it returns something like:

```
file://mnt/.../photoname.jpg
```

When I get a `vertical picture` I get something like that:

```
file://myappcachefolder/modified.jpg?342465654645
```

I think it creates a temp picture with the correct orientation in my cache app folder. But this path is not persistent and when I close and open my app all pictures are the same.

I'm using `resolveLocalFileSystemURL (fileEntry.toURL())` to get the path.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean with `all pictures are the same`?

Comment: yes, all the pictures that I show in my app are the same image. No matter that the path is modified.jpg?42477927 or modified.jpg?29837282. I think it's a cache problem